# GWT: RemoteServiceServlet & HttpServletRequest: problems in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, gwt-rpc

I want to unit test my project, particularly, login function.
I use HttpSession to set or get session key, so I have to acquire a HttpServletRequest

```
final HttpServletRequest request = getThreadLocalRequest();
```

and then

```
final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

When I run the application from a usual entry point, all goes well.
But when I call similar RPC from my UnitTest case, getThreadLocalRequest() returns null
After some digging I realized that RemoteServiceServlet function service() is not called from UnitTest mode while it is called when I debug my application directly.

Is there some way to make HttpServletRequest work properly even from UnitTest mode?

Comment: Yes, I use GWTTestCase, smth like this: public class ServerSecurityTest extends GWTTestCase{/*tests*/}

Comment: All other RPC calls (no session info is used) work completely well in test mode